# Duplicating Collections including the object’s view status

Tags: collections, outliner, duplicate

I have multiple ‘master’ collections each containing further collections and objects within them. Many of the ‘sub’ collections and objects are hidden from the screen.

When I duplicate a master collection within the outliner , each object/collection is duplicated (good!) BUT the view status of the sub collections/objects are all set to visible (!!!) resulting in a garbled mess in the viewport! This means considerable time trying to hide the various sub-collections/objects to match the original collection.

I must be doing something wrong!!! Is there a way of duplicating an entire collection including the view status of each object?

Thanks.
(Blender 3.5.0)

Comment: You're right, it would make more sense if it kept the original settings, maybe it needs to be reported as a mistake